# Retrieving Firebase Database value Swift Xcode

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a lite problem, I cannot recover the carte value in my database. when i get there for username. But the path is good.

My code :

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadCarte()
```

}

```
func loadCarte(){
        var ref: DatabaseReference!

        ref = Database.database().reference()
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        ref.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
          // Get user value
          let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
          let Carte = value?["carte"] as? String ?? ""
            self.carteButton.setTitle(Carte + " cartes", for: .normal)
          // ...
          }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

I manage to recover other values but not that one, can that come from the fact that its being an Integer?

Thank's in Advance

EDIT : my Json structure of a User Type under users > userID

```
    {
  "carte" : 10,
  "email" : "apperce.v@gmail.com",
  "username" : "vicro87000"
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the JSON from the database (as text, no screenshot). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have edited my answer ;) but I can retrieve username, it's work perfectly but for "carte" it doesn't :/

Answer (score 2):

You're storing a numeric value in the `carte` property, so you're casting a numeric value to a string. In Swift you can't cast a number to a string like that.

I've been told by a Swift expert that this is the best way to accomplish the same:

```
let carte = value?["carte"].flatMap { $0 as? Int } .map { String($0) }
```

The `flatMap` operation here unwraps the int value from inside the optional that it's in. Then the `map` converts the int value to a string. Calling the String initializer in the `map` closure is required because Swift Ints are not castable to String types.

Comment: That is one super-sexy answer which works. However, it may be a bit overdone. lol.

Comment: Oh and this... *Swift Ints are not castable to String types.*...... [see this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-convert-an-int-to-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're structure is:

```
uid_0
  "carte" : 10,
  "email" : "apperce.v@gmail.com",
  "username" : "vicro87000"
```

And you want to read in the child values, here's some code to read that node

```
let thisUser = ref.child("users").child(uid)
thisUser.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    let email = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "email").value as? String ?? "No email"
    let userName = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "username").value as? String ?? "No username"
    let carte = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "carte").value as? Int ?? 0
    print(email, username, carte)
})
```

So the carte var will be an Int and can be used in a label

```
myTextField.text = "\(carte)"
```

or cast to a String

```
let myIntAsString = String(carte)
```

this

```
as? Int ?? 0
```

is called a nil coalescing operator and protects your code in case the value is set to nil, it actually is set to 0 so you're code doesn't crash.

As a side note, this is dangerous

```
userID!
```

as force-unwrapping an optional can lead to a crash

Better to do

```
guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else {return}
let uid = user.uid
```